# Is there a simple way to list folder contents in Spring MVC or Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm developing a web service application using Spring Boot and I'm new to it. The documentation is in a PDF document I'd like to serve off a directory, i.e. `/docs`, so I placed it in `src/main/resources/public/docs`.

Since the document is versioned and to ease present and future documentation access, I'd rather give around the documents folder path rather than the specific document path, thus having a simple HTML page with a list of the documents in the folder.

Is there something already available in Spring to achieve this result or should I write my own? In the latter case, since I'm new to Spring and Spring Boot, what's the correct way to implement it? I don't need anything fancy, just a blank HTML page with a list of links will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method from [spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

```
public Stream<Path> loadAll() {
    Path rootLocation = Paths.get("<your path>");
    try {
        return Files.walk(rootLocation, 1).filter(path -> !path.equals(rootLocation)).map(rootLocation::relativize);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In order to list files:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String listUploadedFiles(Model model) throws IOException {

    model.addAttribute("files",
            storageService.loadAll()
                    .map(path -> MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                            .fromMethodName(FileUploadController.class, "serveFile", path.getFileName().toString())
                            .build().toString())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    return "uploadForm";
}
```

Where *uploadForm* is html document. For more details check out [guide repo](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files).

Answer (score 0):

**Spring boot actuator** which provides many services OOB

Do a local setup , tweak around and find an API,
Check the endpoint section in below link,
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

All you have to do is to include the spring boot actuator dependency in your pom.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

There are different endpoints available and they give you different information.

Below are some examples:

http://localhost:8080/env or /auditevents or /health